# Bootstrap navbar-brand logo overlapping on collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I've made a typical Bootstrap navbar and it works well on Desktop sizes. By default, when I added my logo wrapped with the navbar-brand class as in their documentation example, the logo overhangs off the navbar. I solved this problem by adding padding to the links themselves. This works fine until I resize the browser to act like a mobile device. When it collapses, the navbar's height decreases to fit the toggle switch and the logo again overhangs. How to I fix this? Did I go about making the height of the navbar the right way by adding padding? Or should I make it a fixed height by specifically assigning it?

The logo is 55px tall by 128px wide.

Here's my HTML:

```
    <nav id="LC-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div id="LC-navbar-header" class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#LC-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <a id="LC-navbar-brand" class="navbar-brand img-responsive" href="../">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../assets/img/logo-horizontal.png">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div id="LC-navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="LC-navbar-links" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="../">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="../shop/">Shop</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../team/">Our Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../about/">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And CSS:

```
#LC-navbar {
    background-color: #202020;
    border: none;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 30px;
}
#LC-navbar-links {
    padding-right: 20px;
}
#LC-navbar-links li {
    padding: 16px 10px;
}
#LC-navbar-links a {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #c0c0c0;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.25s;
    -o-transition: color 0.25s;
    transition: color 0.25s;
}
#LC-navbar-links a:hover {
    color: #BE1E2D;
}
#LC-navbar-links .active > a {
    color: #BE1E2D;
    background: none;
}
#LC-navbar-links .active > a:hover {
    color: #BE1E2D;
    background: none;
}
```

How would I go about changing styles to the navbar when it's collapsed? Obviously to change the overhang problem but also if say I want it to have a different background color when collapsed vs when open?

Comment: you mean, you want your page to be responsive?

Comment: Exactly haha. I mean it is, except for that one part, where the Logo overhangs when it's collapsed.

Comment: did you override the boostrap.css?

Comment: I don't think so.. Even just making a blank site with only a navbar and a logo that's larger than the normal navbar height, it'll overhang without adding padding. When collapsed, even with padding, it overhangs.

Comment: i see, can you please try to omit the collapsed in this one  class="navbar-toggle collapsed" ? and see result.

Comment: I removed the collapsed but they same behavior seems to be happening.

Comment: can you please try to put role="navigation" in your first line ,,,,,it will look like this ................................................... "<nav id="LC-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">"

Comment: Hmm. I usually add that I must have forgot it. I added the role="navigation" and tested it with and without the collapsed class like you suggested before and the same action of the collapsed navbar being smaller in height than the expanded one is happening.

Comment: ahmm,,, did you really omit the whole class or just the collapsed itself? is it working already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggle menu appears lesser than the width of 768px, so use the `max-width: 768px` media-query.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    height: 80px; // Logo will not overhang
  }
  #LC-navbar {
    background-color: #ccc; // Change background color
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 25px; // Adjust toggle position
  }
}
```